# Swift 3 - Interface That Only Segues A Collection View Inside Of A View Controller

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

I'm trying to build a ViewController that has all static elements, but has a collectionView inside of it that when you click on a cell, segues in another collectionView WITHOUT changing the rest of the View. Here is an image of what I'm trying to do:

[image]

The bottom bar and top bar have to update their content when the CollectionView is clicked. Mainly just text labels that need to show the new information of the clicked cell.

Essentially, each CollectionView is a "Tier", and when you click on a cell, it segues to the next "Tier", but the content around it remains in place without moving, but updates it's content as well.

Based on my experience of iOS development, I can't quite conceptualize how I will solve this problem. Passing data back and forth between all of these views and ViewControllers is a nightmare. I tried to do this using XIBs but it just wasn't working out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took me about five minutes to prototype this:

[image]

Here's the storyboard:

[image]

The brown area is a container view. It has an embed segue to a navigation controller. The navigation controller's nav bar is not showing. The navigation controller has a relationship segue to a root view controller which is a collection view controller. The collection view controller has a show segue to the detail view controller.

It's only a prototype, so the only code is the collection view controller saying that it has three cells, plus the tap gesture recognizer on each cell to trigger the show segue. But updating labels in the outer views at the time of the show segue being triggered would obviously be no problem.

Comment: Thanks, I came up with the same thing now. What do you think is the best way to change the labels of the "Master" ViewController's top bar and bottom bar? Should I set up delegation, use NSNotifications, something else? That's really the biggest problem I'm facing now.

Comment: I don't see why this is an issue. You yourself are issuing the command to perform the `show` segue, and surely you have all the information you need at that moment. The top-level view controller, the one containing the labels, in relation to the collection view controller, is `self.parent?.parent` — so you have a direct line to it and can communicate anything you need to communicate. Or, looking at it the other way, you could make the top-level view controller the navigation controller's `delegate` so it is told when a push takes place and can gather the information it needs.

Comment: Thank you.  It's not an issue per say, I was just curious about best practices. I got it working well with NSNotifications to run a method on the "master" VC. It's cleaner than going self.parent?.parent in my opinion because what I have to do is insert subViews on the bottom bar and that seems to be cleaner to include in the "master" view controller, but either could work yes.

Comment: If you want my personal opinion, NSNotification is the _worst_ possible choice in this situation. NSNotification is reasonable for generalized broadcasting, or perhaps as a last resort of desperation when objects are conceptually distant. But that is hardly the case here. As I have said, these view controllers are part of a known hierarchy, and all the parts are in clear and well-defined contact with one another.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need to use a ContainerView. They can be used with a story board or programmatically.

Your parent view controller will have all of the static elements while the collection view controller will exist inside of the container view. If you need to have data shared between the two you can setup a delegate(protocol) relationship.

Comment: Ok, yeah I was looking into this, glad to hear I was sort of heading down the right path. I assume the Container View will have an embedded NavigationController?

Comment: And what do you think about using NSNotifications instead of delegates?

Comment: @ErickMaynard I would say for this a delegate is going to me more appropriate. You have a clear parent child relationship which will make the delegate very easy to set up. NSNotifications in my opinion have much much more overhead, and are not nearly as performant. I usually reserve using notifications for when a delegate would be harder to set up, or when required to by the apple api (some situations with keyboard show/dismiss).

Comment: NSNotifications are also appropriate when you have to notify a number of objects as opposed to just a 1:1 relationship.